# Get Response from JFoenix Dialog

Tags: javafx

I am using JFoenix in my new JavaFX Application. I've successfully created my own message dialog.

```
package Dialog;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDialog;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDialogLayout;
import com.jfoenix.controls.events.JFXDialogEvent;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;


public class OK_Message extends JFXDialog {

    private StackPane Container;
    private JFXDialogLayout Content;
    String DialogText;
    String Headline;

    JFXButton  btn;
    boolean OK = false;

    private BooleanProperty okval;

    public OK_Message(
            StackPane Container,
            String Headline, 
            String DialogText
    ){
        this.Container = Container;
        this.DialogText = DialogText;
        this.Headline = Headline;
    }

    public void ShowDialog(){
        setDialogContainer(Container);
        setContent(getDialogContent());
        setTransitionType(JFXDialog.DialogTransition.TOP);    
        setOverlayClose(false);


        setFocusTraversable(true);
        setOnDialogOpened((JFXDialogEvent event) -> {
            Platform.runLater(()->{
            btn.requestFocus();
        });});


        setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent e)->{
        e.consume();
        if(e.getCode()== KeyCode.ENTER){close();}
        else if(e.getCode()== KeyCode.SPACE){btn.requestFocus();}
        else{}
        });

        show();
    }

    private JFXDialogLayout getDialogContent(){
        Content = new JFXDialogLayout();
        Content.setHeading(HeadLine());
        Content.setBody(Body());


       // Platform.runLater(()->{b.requestFocus();});

        Content.setActions(getButton());
        return Content;
    }

    private Label HeadLine(){
        Label l = new Label(Headline);
        l.setFont(new Font(18));
        return l;
    }

    private GridPane Body(){
        Label l = new Label(DialogText);
        l.setFont(new Font(14));

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(8);
        GridPane.setConstraints(l, 0, 0, 1, 1, HPos.LEFT, VPos.CENTER, Priority.ALWAYS, Priority.ALWAYS, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        grid.getChildren().addAll(l);
        return grid;
    }

    private JFXButton getButton(){
    btn = new JFXButton("OK");
    btn.setButtonType(JFXButton.ButtonType.FLAT);
    btn.setPrefWidth(50);
    btn.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        CloseDialog();
    });
    btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#FFFFFF");
    btn.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if(newValue){
            btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
            }
        }
    });
    return btn;
    }

    private void CloseDialog(){
    close();
    }

}
```

Now I can call my dialog anywhere: like this:

```
Dialog.OK_Message  message = 
new Dialog.OK_Message((StackPane)app_setup.getParent(),
                "Message", 
                "Changes will be affected after restart.");
    message.ShowDialog();
```

I cannot find a way to detect if use has clicked the button or not. Or what key is pressed by the user. If the user has clicked the OK Button I want to do something. Or if the use has pressed some key I want to do some other thing ? How can I listen to the above dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOnKeyPressed` on your **OK_Message** class just like you used inside your class since it is extending the JFXDialog.

```
message.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getCode().getName());
    }
});
```

For listening which button is clicked why not create customEventListenerfor your **OK_Message** class?

In your **OK_Message.java** file create an interface outside of the class like;

```
interface OnEventListener {
    void onButtonCliked(String id);
}
```

and add a new method to your **OK_Message** class as

```
public void setOnEventListener(OnEventListener listener) {
    mOnEventListener = listener;
}
```

First 
Lets change your `getButton()` method to this one to add functionality of creating multiple buttons with different IDs and texts.

```
private JFXButton getButton(String id,String text){
    JFXButton btn = new JFXButton(text);
    btn.setId(id);
    btn.setButtonType(JFXButton.ButtonType.FLAT);
    btn.setPrefWidth(50);
    btn.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        mOnEventListener.onButtonCliked(btn.getId()); //Here we are firing the event
        CloseDialog();
    });
    btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
    return btn;
}
```

In `getDialogContent()` lets create more than one button.

```
Content.setActions(getButton("Button1","OK"),getButton("Button2","CANCEL"));
```

Now you can use listeners after declaring new **OK_Message** objects

```
OK_Message  message = 
    new OK_Message((StackPane)stackpane,
                        "Message",
                        "Changes will be affected after restart.");
message.ShowDialog();
message.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getCode().getName());
    }
});
message.setOnEventListener(new OnEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onButtonCliked(String id) {
        System.out.println(id);
    }
});
```

Determine what do to according to the id observed by `onButtonClicked()` function.